# Find information in text file given setpoints are known

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I know the setpoints `<start point>` and `<end point>` in the text file and I need to use these to find certain information between them which will be used and printed. I currently have `.readlines()` within a different function which is used within the new function to find the information.

Comment: can you post the code you have tried and what the problem is?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve read this

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
flag = False
info = [] # your desired information will be appended as a string in list
with open(your_file, 'r') as file:
   for line in file.readlines():
       if '<start point>' in line: # Pointer reached the start point
           flag = True
       if '<end point>' in line: # Pointer reached the end point
           flag = False
       if flag:  # this line is between the start point and endpoint
           info.append(line)

>> info
['Number=12', 'Word=Hello']
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a job for regular expressions. If you have not yet encountered regular expressions, they are an extremely powerful tool that can basically be used to search for a specific pattern in a text string.

For example the regular expression (or regex for short) `Number=\d+` would find any line in the text document that has `Number=` followed by any number of number characters. The regex `Word=\w+` would match any string starting with `Word=` and then followed by any number of letters.

In python you can use regular expression through the [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). For a great introduction to using regular expressions in python check out [this chapter](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter7/) from the book *Automate the Boring Stuff with Python*. To test out regular expressions [this site](https://regex101.com/) is great.

In this particular instance you would do something like:

```python
import re
your_file = "test.txt"
with open(your_file,'r') as file:
    file_contents = file.read()
number_regex = re.compile(r'Number=\d+')
number_matches = re.findall(number_regex, file_contents)

print(number_matches)
>>> ['Number=12']
```

This would return a list with all matches to the number regex. You could then do the same thing for the word match.